# Laravel 5.2 - Custom form field name and validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, laravel-5

When someone creates an account in the application I'm building, they have to provide a country.

In order to provide the user with a list of countries to choose from, there is a `countries` table with two fields: `id` and `country_code`. The `users` table has a `country_id` field.

I would like to use a select box named `country` instead of `country_id`, but I'm unable to find out how I would accomplish that. Any idea? Of course, validation and stuff still has to work.

Also, is it mandatory to specify the precise field for `countries.id` in the validation code? Right now, I have this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'name' => 'required',
   'country_id' => 'required|exists:countries,id'
]);
```

As said, the attribute name should be `country` instead of `country_id`, but since I have specified the Eloquent relationship between the User and the Country model, doing something like `'required|exists:countries'` should do the trick, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select name="country">
   <option value="1">US</option>
   <option value="2">UK</option>
</select>
```

And validation

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'country' => 'required|integer|exists:countries,id'
]);
```

`country == name attribute`
`countries == table name`

```
So it will check the value from selected option(id) with existing id in countries table
```

If Country exists in table countries with selected ID save user

```
$user = New User;
$user->country_id = $request->input('country');
$user->save();
```

Laravel validation doesn't bind your columns in DB with your inputs names
I would also add `integer` validation before `exists`

Comment: That was much easier than I expected. I used `$request->merge(['country_id' => $request->input('country')]);` so I can use `$user->create($request->all());`. Thanks!

Comment: @Willem-Aart yeap))
But be carefull, setup `$guarded or $fillable array` of columns in you `Model` so it fill only data you allow more to read https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment